# DFA for this language

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, dfa, computation-theory, automata-theory

Σ={ a, b, c, d } 
L={ x ∈ Σ* | x does not start or end with "bab" }

Examples that should be accepted:

- ababa
- ababc
- bbabb
- bbaba
- ab
- ba
- aaaa
- ɛ

Examples that should be rejected:

- bab
- baba
- babc
- cbab
- abab

I tried several times, and got this so far:[image: my try]

the main problem with my dfa is that it accepts "bbab"

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and no, this is not homework, I'm studying for a test.

Comment: You'd need 4^3 states for remembering the last 3 letters (all combinations). Sipser has some good examples illustrating how this is simpler with NFAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I could <del>quickly</del> come up with.

[image: Slightly less gritty drawing]

Comment: Updated now. Ack @templatetypedef for pointing out the problem with the previous version.